# Open Mozilla Firefox with CoCreateInstance function . How do?

Tags: c++, iwebbrowser2

Good morning,

In my C++ code, I would like to open a webpage through Mozilla Firefox and no more Internet explorer. How can I do ?

```
std::string post = utils::to_html_string(postData);
if (SUCCEEDED(OleInitialize(NULL)))
{
    IWebBrowser2*    pBrowser2;

    CoCreateInstance(CLSID_InternetExplorer, NULL, CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER,
        IID_IWebBrowser2, (void**)&pBrowser2);
    if (pBrowser2)
    {
        GEMLOG(InfoLevel, std::string("void IntegratedBrowser::GoTo(" + website + ")").c_str(), "Displaying web page");

        long rc = DisplayPOST(pBrowser2, (char*)website.c_str(), (char*)post.c_str(), (char*)header.c_str());

        GEMLOG(InfoLevel, std::string("void IntegratedBrowser::GoTo(" + website + ")").c_str(), "Calling waitReadyStateComplete");

        pBrowser2->Release();
    }

    OleUninitialize();
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that firefox supplies implementation of IWebBrowser2 COM interface?

Comment: I don't know. Can you help me ?

Comment: If firefox is the default browser, you could use [ShellExecute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecutea) with an "open" verb on the url

Answer (score 0):

I never heard that Firefox provides COM server. Fast search shows that [others](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=245826) also did not hear about Firefox COM/OLE server. You can locate firefox.exe or open page in default browser : [Start the default Internet browser programmatically by using Visual C++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/cpp/start-internet-browser)